# Windows - can I redirect the output of a window class to a bitmap?

Tags: c++, windows

Ok, first a little background.

I have a windows application, which makes use of a third party DLL.

The application has a GUI consisting of "roll your own" controls rather than Windows own, so from the point of view of windows it's just a bitmap (the application draws its own controls in that bitmap, deals with mouse mapping to those controls etc).

The DLL also has a GUI (formed in a similar way as it happens, but that I think is academic in this case), which it writes to a window which is passed to it.

I need that GUI to appear inside mine.

So far, I've achieved something that is acceptable by simply making the window I give the DLL a client of my application's window, which I place in the correct location, the DLL writes directly to the screen.

This, so far as it goes, works fine. THe DLL's GUI displays where it should, and reacts to mouse input as it should.

However there are things I cannot apparantly do in this circumstance, for example I cannot place one of my own GUI elements overlapping the DLL's GUI (because the DLL's window is in front of apps single window), nor, so far as I can see, can I scale the DLL's GUI (the rest of my GUI can be magnified or reduced).

So it would seem preferable to have the DLL draw to a bitmap, which my application can then deal with like every other bitmap. So I'm wondering if this is possible.

I'm afraid that I can't see a way to supply code that will work in a standalone manner, as per Forum guidelines, not least because it is reliant on the third party DLL. But the current functionality can at least be described with the following code snippet

```
HWND createWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND parent_hwnd, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    WNDCLASS wincl;

    if (!GetClassInfo(GetInstance(), L"MyWindowClass", &wincl)) {
        wincl.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
        wincl.hInstance = GetInstance();
        wincl.lpszClassName = s_classname_;
        wincl.lpfnWndProc = &Win32WindowView::ThisWindowProc;
        wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_WINLOGO);
        wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
        wincl.hbrBackground = 0;
        wincl.lpszMenuName = 0;
        if (RegisterClass(&wincl) == 0) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "The window class failed to register.", "Error", 0);
            //return 0;
        }
    }

    HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MyWindowClass", L"Window", WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent_hwnd, NULL, hInstance, this);
    return window;
}

// This is then used in the following way, where "DllHandler" is a wrapper that loads the DLL into memory and deals with passing it instructions.
auto my_dll_hander = new DllHandler("location/of/dll");
HWND dll_window = createWindow(hInstance, my_main_window_hwnd, 20, 20, 200, 200);
my_dll_handler->openGUI(dll_window);
```

The beauty of this currently is that windows deals with both the routing of mouse handling to the DLL's GUI, and the display of that GUI to the screen directly, without me having to do anything more.
The disadvantage, as I've already explained, is that I CAN'T do anything more, even when it would be useful.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can [display a live copy of a window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130513-00/?p=4393/) at a random place in your program, but then you won't be able to interact with it. But it would count as `have the DLL draw to a bitmap, which my application can then deal with like every other bitmap`. Makes scaling possible too.

Comment: Have you considered sub-classing the control? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx I can see the solution being horribly convoluted when it comes time to handle mouse input, but the cost of giving it a try is probably only going to be 10-15 minutes. It's also actually possible that you could force the GUI to be a good size instead, by calling the default handler for `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` before doing your own thing and setting the return values to ones you find more amenable to your needs. Too hard to say - the GUI could be done in so many different ways

Comment: Why not create your own child window and put it on top of the DLL's window? That will also get hit testing right. And input routing. And accessibility.